# How safe are shower rennovations like Bath Fitter? What about mold behind the tile and wall?

Tags: bathroom, shower, mold, renovation

We're wanting to just get a clean stand-up shower in our master, and have had multiple quotes for a gut and replace. Along with these, we've also got a quote from Bath Fitter to do a wrap for about 50% the cost of a full blown renovation (about $4,000 vs $8,000+).

We don't really care what it looks like, as long as it's clean. Our primary concern is mold behind the tiles (floor and walls) -- my understanding is they just put a wrap on the current shower. What happens to the mold in the title and behind the wall?

Comment: You know there is mold behind the existing tiles already?

Comment: All houses have mold, but if you have mold in the bathroom that's visible, I'd say that more important that cleaning it up is solving the root of the problem - moist air hanging around. A full renovation may do that, but a wrap likely doesn't.

Comment: @Drew well I can see mold in the cracks between the tiles, so I assume yes.

Comment: @bombcar I was thinking that maybe the mold was growing because of cracks in the tiles and grout -- and I was hoping that closing those up with just a single wrap would seal it enough to stop future growth and maybe dry-up what's there?

Comment: How long do you plan on living in this house?

Comment: A year or two more at most - we'd like to put it on the market this summer honestly.

Comment: How bad is it? If you're selling this summer, just bleach the living daylights out of it and seal the grout.